# Could not publish to the server - java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, maven

I am not able to run my application. Whenever i start my server, it gives me "could not publish to the server" error. Can anybody help me please? I have been stuck in this problem from past 1 week.

My pom.xml file details are mentioned below.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.marryme</groupId>
    <artifactId>mm</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>

    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    <!-- Web -->
    <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <servlet.version>3.0.1</servlet.version>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.1.7.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <spring-security.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring-security.version>

    <!-- Spring Data -->
    <spring-framework.data.version>1.8.0.RELEASE</spring-framework.data.version>

    <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
    <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    <!-- jackson json JSON Processing API -->
    <jackson.databind-version>2.2.3</jackson.databind-version>

    <!-- JUnit test -->
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

    <!-- Quartz scheduling framework -->
    <quartz.scheduling.version>2.2.1</quartz.scheduling.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Other Servlet Web dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsp.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Validation API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring JDBC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring ORM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.data.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring REST jackson JSON Processing API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.databind-version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Excel view -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- PDF view -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Quartz scheduling framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>${quartz.scheduling.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- gson - Convert Java object to json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Rest API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>




</dependencies>

<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What about the code which produces this error?

Comment: maybe the error log would help no?

Comment: After selecting the project when I click on run, then it produces error. There is no error in code just some deployment issue. This project was working in my different system

Comment: The maven repository can be corrupt. It is best to remove the complete repository and update all projects in the workspace.

Comment: Give a whole log error, there is no way this error is that short. The cause may be a lot of reasons - deployment assembly/wrong server configuration/some errors in code etc.

Comment: Whatzs: From where can I find the logs?? Do you want me to give apache logs?

Comment: Rishi: How can I remove the complete repository? Could you please tell me the steps for eclipse?